# May I place "using namespace std" into my namespace, that in a header?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

I am writing a small library. Declaration of my classes, functions and others, that uses standard library are in a header file. I know that putting "using namespace" into header is a bad practic. May I put my code in separate namespace and then put "using namespace" into it?
Like this:

```
// header.h
namespace My
{
    using namespace std;
    // declarations
}
```

Will it be good?

Comment: you can, and it will bring the things from that namespace into yours, but it is generally bad to use `using namespace` anywhere.

Comment: Never put `using namespace std` anywhere!

Comment: Regarding the specific `using namespace std` [here's a detailed post on why not to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it!
Simply use fully qualified names or using declaration for specific symbols that you want to use.
With this, You will just end up importing the contents of entire `std` namespace in your namespace `My` and essentially the header file `header.h`. Basically, it is going to give you namespace pollution with lot of unused symbols and also increase the compilation time of every translation unit where you include this header.

Comment: Is better putting any using declaration into namespace than putting it directly in the header file, or not?

Comment: @Dmitry: You are asking to chose between two evils.Yes, your method is less evil but doesn't mean its not evil.

Answer (score 1):

You may do that but it is not a good idea because this can lead to ambiguious names.